# Angular Data Visualization using chartjs and ng2

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have *AngularJS* project which summarize data and visualizes it by number of female and male in months. Now I want to allow user to select a year and view visualization for all months of that particular year.

Currently my graph look like this:

[image: my graph]

Here is my code so far:

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule,
ChartsModule,
AppRoutingModule
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my full project https://angular-ivy-gewusg.stackblitz.io

Comment: What is it you're asking? It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: I want user to be able to select a year from drop down and view the visualization. @CascadiaJS

Comment: That's a broad question. Be more specific. What part of the app isn't working? What have you tried already?

Comment: Program is working, but i want to add feature for user to select year and display the graph, currently if given data contains 1991-02-14 and 1993-02-18 it treats as february, and draw the graph, but that are data from different years, so i want user to enter a specific year and draw the graph

Comment: Also i would want to show total customer registered on particular day  (today) and total number of customer since day one